# how to publish with active pulldown to filter the displayed data?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to publish all employee's name then I will provide a filter (maybe in the shape of pulldown choice). So the user can select from the pulldown, for example: male employee, female employee, an employee who age above 40 etc.

Is it possible in the publish page? any solution?

link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gdvwnZk2w9eh0nhYIuqFiBAbu1Q1lByqLMqQhMmqF1s/edit#gid=0

Comment: @player0 Hi i just added the link. So i want to publish it to web and the user can interact with the pulldown , so they can select which data they want to view using the filter. Is it possible ? we can add function() to that pulldown but how to make the pulldown accessible so viewer can click it ?

Answer (score 0):

formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(C2="All",      FILTER(A6:C, A6:A<>""), 
 IF(C2="Male",     FILTER(A6:C, C6:C="Male"), 
 IF(C2="Female",   FILTER(A6:C, C6:C="Female"), 
 IF(C2="Age > 35", FILTER(A6:C, B6:B>35), )))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: But when i publish the page  , the pulldown is not accessible (it become a static text) . So viewer can't change the pulldown to control the data they want to see. The goal is to let viewer choose the filter (by selecting from pulldown)

Comment: for that, you will need to grant Edit rights for everyone with link otherwise dropdown is not accessible